# How to iterate through nested Dictionary<string, object>?

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON file that I need to deserialize using the class `System.Web.Script.Serialization`. The following code:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\file.json");
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

creates a nested dictionary, something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Object> outerDictionary;
Dictionary<string, Object> middleDictionary;
Dictionary<string, string> innerDictionary;
```

I now need to grab some of the values from the innerDictionary into a C# object class, like:

```
public class Location
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Street { get; set; }
   public string City { get; set; }
   public string State { get; set; }
   public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

So my question is, how can I iterate over the nested disctionary to get the values I need at the innermost level?

**UPDATE**

With the help of `Jonesopolis` I now have the correct loop structure, but I am still unable to get the values from the innermost dictionary?

```
foreach (var outer in dict)
{
    foreach (var middle in (Dictionary<string, object>)outer.Value)
    {
        foreach (var inner in (ArrayList)middle.Value)
        {
            foreach (var loc in (Dictionary<string, object>)inner)
            {
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the nested `foreach` in [Jonesopolis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39101360/261050), then you can use LINQ this way:

```
var data = from outer in dict
           from middle in (Dictionary<string, object>) outer.Value
           from inner in (Dictionary<string, string>) middle.Value
           select new { outer, middle, inner };

foreach (var item in data) {
    // do things with item.inner
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to work with those objects:

```
foreach(var outer in dict)
{
    foreach (var middle in (Dictionary<string, object>) outer.Value)
    {
         foreach (var inner in (Dictionary<string, string>) middle.Value)
         {
              var location = new Location();
              location.Id = inner["Id"]; 
              //etc..
         }      
    }
}
```

though, it would be much better to create a class structure that you can deserialize your json to, that accurately represents your data, instead of casting Dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I try your solution I get the error: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'.`

Comment: well then your types are not actually dictionaries

Comment: Thanks @Jonesopolis, you were correct. My types were wrong. I have updated the original post with the correct structure, but I'm still unable to get the values from the innermost dictionary?